# mimo icap netty implementation client sample code required

Tags: netty

I am using Netty for ICAP implementation 1.0.1.GA

But am unable to implement a working solution. Has anyone worked with it and got a working solution? The documentation link on the website http://icap.io/ doesn't work either.

My requirement is to check the attachments in the request for virus.

Any help or heads-on will be great!!!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example below opens a socket to the ICAP server, prepares an Out stream and an In stream for the socket. Then prepare an ICAP header and write it on the Out stream. The response from ICAP server will be written to the In stream. Read it and use it as you want.
Instead of OPTIONS you could use RESPMOD, REQMOD as per your requirement. The below code returns you the options provided by the ICAP server.

The REQMOD, RESMOD header for ICAP could be

```
String requestBuffer = 
            "RESPMOD icap://"+serverIP+"/"+icapService+" ICAP/"+VERSION+"\r\n"
            +"Host: "+serverIP+"\r\n"
            +"User-Agent: "+USERAGENT+"\r\n"
            +"Allow: 204\r\n"
            +"Preview: "+previewSize+"\r\n"
            +"Encapsulated: res-hdr=0, res-body="+resBody.length()+"\r\n"
            +"\r\n"
            +resBody
            +Integer.toHexString(previewSize) +"\r\n";
```

You can use the above header for getting a response from ICAP server.
You can write the file to the Out stream needed to be sent to the ICAP server.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.Socket;

public class MyTestICAPClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Socket socket = null;
    Writer out = null;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket("10.4.255.101", 1344);//ICAP server address/port

            out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "ISO-8859-1");

            out.write("OPTIONS icap://10.4.255.101/avscan ICAP/1.0" + "\r\n"
                    + "Host: 10.4.253.100"+"\r\n"
                    + "User-Agent: IT-Kartellet ICAP Client/0.9"+"\r\n"//your User-Agent
                    + "Encapsulated: null-body=0\r\n"
                    + "\r\n");

            out.write("\r\n");
            out.flush();
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
            socket.close();
        }catch(Exception exp){
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

[The ICAP Codec for JBoss Netty](https://github.com/jmimo/netty-icap) might be useful to you, although it seems like it's not being maintained now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Trustin. My requirement was a bit different from the normal ICAP requests in which the web-site's URI is mentioned. My need is to hit the ICAP server from within my application and not to go to a specific URI wrapping my HTTPRequest in the ICAPRequest. I have provided an answer to my question. Finally got it working.